# How do I reset and restore an Ubuntu without the password

Tags: restore

I was recently given a asus laptop with Ubuntu in it but they cans remember the password and I can’t do anything on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing Ubuntu
1: Bring a Flash drive of 8Gb or more
2: Download your own choice of Ubuntu ISO from "https://www.ubuntu.com/#download"
3: Make the drive bootable and Burn ISO in it.
4: reboot, go into Bios setup and Boot from USB
5: Follow the steps, and make your laptop brand New... :)

Comment: Re-installation is the last hope when there is nothing working.

Comment: You got a laptop from someone, first thing u do is refresh it...

Comment: I agree with Hamza. You never know what they did to the system and since there is no way to "reset to factory defaults" in Ubuntu it's better to reinstall IMO.